# How to use multiple databases for unit test cases in django pytest

Tags: django, pytest-django

I have been working on a django application which uses multiples databases through database router like the following. I want to write unit test cases for the apis developed using Django Rest Framework.

```
class MultiDbRouter(object):
    """
        Router for handling multiple database connections
        based on the db configs in the request object
    """

    def _multi_db(self):
        if hasattr(request_cfg, 'db'):
            if request_cfg.db in settings.DATABASES:
                return request_cfg.db
            else:
                raise Http404
        else:
            return 'default'

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
            Set database for reading based on request config
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'survey':
            return 'survey'
        if model._meta.app_label != 'analytics':
            return 'default'
        return self._multi_db()

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
            Set database for writing based on request config
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'survey':
            return 'survey'
        if model._meta.app_label != 'analytics':
            return 'default'
        return self._multi_db()

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
            allow relation between objects
        """
        return True

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        """
            allow syncing of database
        """
        return True
```

I have started using pytest for writing the testcases, but as I read the docs of pytest-django library, it says that "Currently pytest-django does not specifically support Django’s multi-database support."

Is there any way to workaround this limitation? Or should I use some other library other than pytest-django to write the unit test cases? If yes, which one?

What is the ideal way of going forward?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the documentation for pytest says use Django's normal testing classes. [Tests and multiple databases - Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/advanced/#tests-and-multiple-databases)

Comment: I read that, but then what is the use of pytest? I will have to write all the test cases using Django's Testcase.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use pytest and multiple databases with all tests written using the usual pytest syntax. In your `conftest.py` file, add the following to the top:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

TestCase.databases = {"default", "survey"}
```

This will cause all pytest tests to use both of your databases.

The documentation on pytest-django alludes to there being no way to configure multi-database support on a test by test basis or by using pytest fixtures. Of course the above might make your tests suite slower as your tests will be rolling back changes across two databases between every test.

I got this solution from [this comment](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/pull/397#issuecomment-261987751) on pytest-django and the [django docs on multi database support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.databases).